# Merge two audio file failed

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 \"Operation Stopped\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media.})")

{origin : caf lpcm, destination: aiff or wav or caf}

Here is the code:

```
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        self.prepareToCombineMedia(composition)

        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!

        let tmpFilePath = FileUtils.tempFile(ext: "caf")
        exportSession.outputURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: tmpFilePath)
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            if exportSession.status == .completed {
                print("completed")
                print(tmpFilePath)
                subscriber.onCompleted()
            } else {
                subscriber.onError(LeafError.runtime(message: exportSession.error.debugDescription))
                FileUtils.rm(tmpFilePath)
            }
        }
```

It's only can be merge to m4a or mov. I need caf or wav or aiff file , Help...

Answer (score 1):

replace this line :

```
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!
```

with :

```
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
```

hopefully it will work